# Аффинный шифр 3-го порядка

Tags: python, криптография

написать аффинный шифр 3-го(к-го) порядка, допустимым с текстом "hello world" к примеру, сам шифр имеет матрицу, выступающую в роли ключа, и вспомогательный ключ, на который по идее мы должны умножать нашу матрицу, то есть первый ключ. Сообщение разбивается на k-граммы. Каждая k-грамма X замещается k-граммой. Каждая k-грамма X' криптотекста замещается k-граммой D(X’)=A’X’+S’, где A’=A-1 и S’=–A’S – расшифровывающий ключ.
Ниже мой код, однако мне кажется легче будет создать новый, проблема возникает на процессе  декодирования, на сколько я понимаю:

```
import numpy as np

def affine_encrypt(message, key1, key2):
    message = message.upper().replace(" ", "")

    letter_to_num = {chr(i + 65): i for i in range(26)}
    num_to_letter = {i: chr(i + 65) for i in range(26)}

    ciphertext = ""

    nums = [letter_to_num[char] for char in message]

    n = len(nums)
    m = int(np.ceil(n / 3))
    nums = np.pad(nums, (0, m * 3 - n), mode='constant')
    nums = np.reshape(nums, (m, 3))

    # шифр с использованием матричного умножения
    prod = np.dot(nums, key1)
    key2 = np.tile(key2.T, (m, 1))
    nums = np.mod(prod + key2, 26)

    # Преобразование чисел обратно в буквы и добавление к зашифрованному тексту
    for row in nums:
        for num in row:
            ciphertext += num_to_letter[num]

    return ciphertext


def affine_decrypt(ciphertext, key1, key2):
    letter_to_num = {chr(i + 65): i for i in range(26)}
    num_to_letter = {i: chr(i + 65) for i in range(26)}

    plaintext = ""

    nums = [letter_to_num[char] for char in ciphertext]

    # Преобразование чисел в матрицу
    n = len(nums)
    m = int(np.ceil(n / 3))
    nums = np.pad(nums, (0, m * 3 - n), mode='constant')
    nums = np.reshape(nums, (m, 3))

    # дешифровка с использованием матричного умножения
    key2 = np.tile(key2.T, (m, 1))
    try:
        nums = np.round(np.mod(np.dot(nums - key2, np.linalg.inv(key1)), 26)).astype(int)
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        print("Error: Key 1 is not invertible!")
        return ""

    # Преобразование чисел обратно в буквы и добавление в открытый текст
    for row in nums:
        for num in row:
            plaintext += num_to_letter[num]

    plaintext = plaintext[:n]

    return plaintext

key1 = np.array([[4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4]])  # 1 ключ
key2 = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])  # 2 ключ
message = "Hello world"

ciphertext = affine_encrypt(message, key1, key2)
print("Ciphertext:", ciphertext)

plaintext = affine_decrypt(ciphertext, key1, key2)
print("Plaintext:", plaintext)
```

Вот результат выполнения: `Ciphertext: OBNVDXDWONLJ Plaintext: DSDDQGWPBDAA`

Comment: Забыл вот результат:                                                                                                                            Ciphertext: OBNVDXDWONLJ
Plaintext: DSDDQGWPBDAA

Comment: Лучше добавить результат в вопрос, а не в коммент к вопросу)